# Router redirection after user already logged in wont work

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Whenever I call signOut function from my component it doesn't work at all, it worked before but stopped after adding the code below in `router.beforeEach`.
I need to redirect the user to ('/') if he's already logged in, by checking the `authState`. How can I fix the issue?

```js
 if(to.path == '/login' && authState == true) {
     return next('/')
   }
```

```js
  async signOut() {
      await auth.logout();
      await localStorage.removeItem("authenticated");
      await router.push({ name: "Login" });
    },
```

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const { authState } = useAuthStore(router.pinia);
   
  if(to.path == '/login' && authState == true) {
     return next('/')
   }

  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.authRequired)) {
    authState
      ? next()
      : next('/login');
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Comment: Did you try to get log in beforeEach? For example what is the value of `authState` or `to`?

Comment: AuthState is just a getter and returns true/false `return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("authenticated"))`. I can log in the page, but I can't log out. It stopped working after I added the `if(to.path =='/login'...`